# Telerik:Radgridview Export to excel

Tags: telerik-grid

I am using a `telerik Radgridview` in one of the my reports.
I have to export the result into Excel, for that I am using telerik's inbuild `ExportToExcel`
function this will export my result successfully to excel format. But my requirement is that I want to show the Header also in the generated Excel

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. To achieve this we need to add following event:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ExcelMLExportRowCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridExcelBuilder.GridExportExcelMLRowCreatedArgs e)
{
        if (e.RowType == Telerik.Web.UI.GridExcelBuilder.GridExportExcelMLRowType.HeaderRow)
        {
           e.Worksheet.WorksheetOptions.PageSetup.PageHeaderElement.Data = "This is the DRAFT Data";
        }
}
```

It will work for me.